# How to retrieve an enum index value based on char array? in C++ (cpp)

Tags: c++, chess

Disclaimer: New to programming, learning on the fly. This is my first post and apologize if the question is not written clearly.

I am trying to go through a tutorial on building a chess engine, but it is written in C and I am attempting to convert it to C++ code. The idea of the code is to enter a char and retrieve the index value of an enum. I am getting a compile error because of this code.
How do I approach this as it isn't clear to me after trying different ideas.

E.g. `std::cout << CHAR_TO_PIECE['k'];` with expected output of 11.

in `"typedefs.h"`

```
enum Piece {P, N, B, R, Q, K, p, n, b, r, q, k};
```

in `"board.h"`

```
extern const int CHAR_TO_PIECE[];
```

and in `board.c`

```
// convert ASCII character pieces to encoded constants
int CHAR_TO_PIECE[] = {
    ['P'] = P,
    ['N'] = N,
    ['B'] = B,
    ['R'] = R,
    ['Q'] = Q,
    ['K'] = K,
    ['p'] = p,
    ['n'] = n,
    ['b'] = b,
    ['r'] = r,
    ['q'] = q,
    ['k'] = k
};
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, first of all try to create a [mre] to show us, preferably one we can copy-paste directly to replicate the error. Secondly, and even if we have the perfect [mre], also please copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build log. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Where did you get the idea that your `board.c` is how you define a mapping from `char`s to `enum`s? Is that C code from the original or your best guess at what the syntax should look like?

Comment: @NathanPierson from a YouTube tutorial with GitHub: [link](https://github.com/maksimKorzh/chess_programming/blob/master/src/bbc/bbc_1.1b/bbc.c)

Comment: Fascinating bit of C syntax I didn't know about. Cool.

Comment: You could give the enum the underlying type `char` and assign the elements values equal to the letter.  E.g. something like `enum Peice : char { a = 'a', ...}`, but it's a bit of a hack, and you should know what your are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to return specific enum for you char input .

```
enum Piece {P, N, B, R, Q, K, p, n, b, r, q, k};

Piece charToPiece(char ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
        case 'P':
            return P;
        case 'N':
            return N;
        case 'B':
            return B;
        case 'R':
            return R;
        case 'Q':
            return Q;
        case 'K':
            return K;
        case 'p':
            return p;
        case 'n':
            return n;
        case 'b':
            return b;
        case 'r':
            return r;
        case 'q':
            return q;
        case 'k':
            return k;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I was looking to this as a solution before but didn't think of the enum name 'Piece' in front of the function. This was great.

Comment: Note: if `ch` is not an acceptable value, this code will return an *indeterminate value*, which is *undefined behavior*. You need to either `return` a default value, or `throw` an exception.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. I did get that error, so I added default:  return NO_PIECE; to the case statement, and added NO_PIECE to the enum.

Answer (score 1):

A more C++ way to handle this is to use a `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`), eg:

```
#include <map>

enum Piece {P, N, B, R, Q, K, p, n, b, r, q, k};

extern const std::map<char, Piece> CHAR_TO_PIECE;
```

```
// convert ASCII character pieces to encoded constants
const std::map<char, Piece> CHAR_TO_PIECE = {
    {'P', P},
    {'N', N},
    {'B', B},
    {'R', R},
    {'Q', Q},
    {'K', K},
    {'p', p},
    {'n', n},
    {'b', b},
    {'r', r},
    {'q', q},
    {'k', k}
};
```

```
std::cout << (int) CHAR_TO_PIECE['k'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of enums with 2 x 26 entries (upper and lowercase), and assign every relevant entry the correct enum. This must be coded manually. With such a correspondence table, character lookup is immediate. (You can also reserve a "unassigned" value if needed.)